# How do I summarize multiple job cost data to one contract?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have multiple tables I am pulling data from to create a report that provides a list of all contracts with the date of most recent invoice, date of most recent job cost, total cost amount, and total billed amount.

The tables I have are:

- Contract details where I'm pulling contract number, department, status, contract amount, billed amount
- AP invoice where I'm pulling last invoice date
- Job cost where I'm pulling job number, total cost, and last job cost date
- Job details that joins contract details and job cost

My query is currently written as shown below. The issue I'm running into is with job cost. There can be multiple jobs assigned to a contract, so my data set is returning multiple results (see image below). I can't figure out how to set either my query or the SSRS report to display the details by contract items only (one line per contract).

```
SELECT 
c.Contract
,c.Department
,c.Contract + ' ' + c.Description as ContractDescription
,c.ContractStatus
,c.ContractAmt
,c.BilledAmt
,(Select MAX(ap.Mth) from APInvoice ap where j.JCCo = ap.JCCo AND j.Job = ap.Job) as RecentInvoice
,(Select MAX(jc.Mth) from JobCost jc where j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job) as RecentJobCost
,(Select Sum(jc.ActualCost) from JobCost jc where j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job) as ActualCost
,(Select Distinct jc.Job from JobCost jc where j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job) as JobNumber
,c.udProjFolderRecd
,c.udBillStatus

FROM ContractDetails c
LEFT JOIN JobDetails j ON j.JCCo = c.JCCo AND j.Contract = c.Contract

WHERE c.JCCo = (@Company)
AND c.ContractStatus IN (@ContractStatus) 
AND c.Department IN (@Department)
```

[image]

Comment: How would you want to consolidate the columns that can't be summed if you want to display 1 contract per row? Ex. Job Number, Last Job Cost, etc.

Comment: @papermoon88 - Job number can be removed. I only have it in there now for reference to understand the data. For Last Invoice and Last Job Cost, I would want the most recent date for all jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
  SELECT
  Contract,
  Department,
  ContractDescription,
  ContractStatus,
  ContractAmt,
  Max(RecentInvoice) AS RecentInvoice,
  Max(RecentJobCost) AS RecentJobCost,
  Sum(BilledAmt)   AS TotalBilledAmt
FROM   (SELECT
          c.Contract,
          c.Department,
          c.Contract + ' ' + c.Description AS ContractDescription,
          c.ContractStatus,
          c.ContractAmt,
          c.BilledAmt,
          (SELECT             Max(ap.Mth)           FROM   APInvoice ap WHERE  j.JCCo = ap.JCCo AND j.Job = ap.Job)      AS RecentInvoice,
          (SELECT             Max(jc.Mth)           FROM   JobCost jc   WHERE  j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job)      AS RecentJobCost,
          (SELECT             Sum(jc.ActualCost)    FROM   JobCost jc   WHERE  j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job)      AS ActualCost,
          (SELECT DISTINCT             jc.Job       FROM   JobCost jc   WHERE  j.JCCo = jc.JCCo AND j.Job = jc.Job)      AS JobNumber,
          c.udProjFolderRecd,
          c.udBillStatus
        FROM   ContractDetails c
               LEFT JOIN JobDetails j   ON j.JCCo = c.JCCo  AND j.Contract = c.Contract
        WHERE  c.JCCo = ( @Company )
               AND c.ContractStatus IN ( @ContractStatus )
               AND c.Department IN ( @Department )) contractsummary
GROUP  BY Contract,
          Department,
          ContractDescription,
          ContractStatus,
          ContractAmt
```